# I don't surely understand why this code works. Especially at the part "i=strstr(s + k, t) - s;", from my understanding the strstr() returns a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-data-type

The program does what is supposed to do, to extract the last occurence of a string in a string, but since `strstr()` is returning a pointer, why does the "minus string" do to make it unsigned and give the value of the last occurence?

Input:

> ana si mariana canta la nai
> na

Ouput:

> ana si mariana canta la i

The code is bellow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char s[256], t[256];
int main()
{
    unsigned i, n, k = 0, x = 0;
    gets(s);
    gets(t);
    n = strlen(t);
    while(k < strlen(s) && x < strlen(s))
    {
        i = strstr(s + k, t) - s;
        k = i + n;
        x = strstr(s + k, t) - s;
    }
    strcpy(s + i, s + i + n);
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to change data types from pointer to unsigned or int, see what happens, change the position of "s", like "s - strstr(...)" but the code didn't work anymore.

Comment: İt seems that you are trying to modify the string s after finding the last occurrence of t. This may lead to undefined behavior because you're altering memory that you shouldn't. Try memmove to shift the suffix of s over the removed substring.

Comment: It's called *pointer arithmetic*, if you subtract one pointer from another you get a integer value which is the distance between the two pointers. Eg. `int* p = something; int* q = p + 10; cout << (q - p);` prints 10.

Comment: But why `strstr(s + k, t) - s` is positive, shouldn't it be a negative value?

Comment: Does it help if the pointer arithmetic is expanded, to say that `strstr(s + k, t) - s` is equivalent to `strstr(&s[k], t) - &s[0]`?   In other words, it is the index of a character in `s`, after the first character and indices always increase to the right.   Although subtracting pointers *can* produce a negative value, it doesn't in this case  [assuming that the substring is present, so `strstr()` does not return a null pointer].

Comment: @nex Because `strstr(s+k, t)` returns a pointer that is greater than `s`, i.e. `strstr(s + k, t) >= s` is true. When you substract a smaller pointer from a larger pointer you get a positive result, just like numbers.

Comment: The difference of two pointers is not a pointer, it is an integer. The only way `strstr(s + k, t) - ` can be negative is if `k` is negative, and as `k` is declared as `unsigned` that's impossible.

Comment: What are the new functions in C++ in place of gets, strlen, strcpy? Or where could I find them?

Comment: @nex The `std::string` type from the C++ standard library replaces all those functions. `std::string` has been part of C++ for **over thirty years** so you really must be reading some ancient documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two pointers refer to elements of same array (or one element beyond the end), result of substraction is a signed distance netween them, in elements, where result is positive if left pointer refers to an element with greater index.

Aside from output this is ideomatically a C code, not C++ code. It contains typical mistakes one can use with pointer arithmetics and contains possible buffer overrun - you are slipping from `s` array into `t` array.

`s` is a pointer to beginning of array, and `strstr` returns a pointer to found occurence OR `nullptr`. So your code got two possible bugs:

- substring not found: `nullptr - s` does not have defined result. Some implementations have it as if `s` was an incorrect pointer (negative value) and some outright return `0`.
- `k` is greter than `strlen(s)` - second call of strstr does have risk to run into uninitialized memory, into `t` or fail, no check was there.